# How to remove a ListBoxItem according to its value when a ListBoxItem is made of more objects?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a ListBox and each ListBoxItem is made of two images and one label. From the application I bind the Content value of the label and the Source values of the images.

Now I would like to be able to search in the Listbox the ListBoxItem with a specific value of the label, but I have no ideas on how to do that.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can bind to a `CollectionViewSource` as `ItemsSource` of the Listbox. Here is an example for filtering: http://wpftutorial.net/DataViews.html

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach (item in listBox.Items)
{
    if (item is typeof(ListBoxItem) && item.Value == someValueToCheck)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: But my listboxitem has three things, 2 images and a label. Would this work? I don't think so.

Comment: @user3603880 then you should use something like item.FindName("your label name here"); or, for example, item.GetVisualChild();